# Ruby on Rails for reverse-auction type app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-associations

Need help, please!

If I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_shipments
  has_many :shipments, through: :user_shipments

  def posted_shipments
    user_shipments.where(role: 'shipper').map(&:shipment)
  end

  def carrier_shipments
    user_shipments.where(role: 'carrier').map(&:shipment)
  end
end
```

and

```
class Shipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_shipments
  has_many :users, through: :user_shipments

  def shippers
    user_shipments.where(role: 'shipper').map(&:user)
  end

  def carriers
    user_shipments.where(role: 'carrier').map(&:user)
  end
end
```

and

```
class UserShipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :shipment
end
```

how do we associate `carrier` with `shipper` such that for every `shipment` created by `shipper`, the latter can view his `carriers` for a reverse-auction type of app we're trying to build for a project?

In other words, a `User` `shipper` creates a `shipment` and a `User` `carrier` can bid on the same, but only on those that belong to his `shipper`, or when a `shipment` is created, a `shipper` can instantly see his list of `carriers` and view their bids?

Thanks so much! We're new to this.

Comment: You should really start accepting answers to your questions (click the checkmark next to the voting buttons for the best answer to each question).

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all carriers from an individual user making a shipment:

```
@associated_carriers = user.posted_shipments.map{ |shipment| shipment.carriers}.uniq
```

To get a list of all shippers from an individual user wanting to see new shipments:

```
@associated_shippers = user.carrier_shipments.map{|shipment| shipment.shippers}.uniq
```

From those two lists of users, you can then iterate through the individual users to get info about each.

For a user's `@associated_shippers`, you can list those shippers posted_shipments by doing:

```
@associated_shippers.each do |shipper_user|
  # in the auction view:
  # shipper_user.posted_shipments, etc.
end
```

and for a user's `@associated_carriers`, you can list those carriers carrier_shipments by doing:

```
@associated_carriers.each do |carrier_user|
  # in the auction view:
  # carrier_user.carrier_shipments, etc.
end
```